# VS Code Python debug Multiple files - while stopping at breakpoint shows blank file and not the original file with breakpoints

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I have a python project that has multiple python files. A function from one file may call a function from another and so on so forth. I have 2 issues, when I put breakpoints they work well in the 1st file but they don't hit a row if a function gets called form another file. The way I made it work was by either clicking step-into in the 1st .py file itself or using Function breakpoints by giving actual names of the function. However, what gets shown is some file that's blank at the top and shows lines that's different from the actual code. This makes it difficult to understand what line of code it is as even the line numbers are different. I can see some variables being called that are similar. I am a noob at debugging in VS code, pardon me if am not able to describe the problem properly.

[Entry point of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ9pO.png)

[Actual file that contains the Function being called from another .py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xv98.png)

[Blank File that shows up during the function breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CEHY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you encounter. I made a simple case to add breakpoints in two associated files. It's no problem. I hope you can provide a code that can reproduce the problem and attach your launch.json

Comment: Hi @MingJie-MSFT, This is the launch.json with pretty much all default values.

// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]

Comment: Provide some more details to reproduce the issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example